# Python Nested List manipulation

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists, list-manipulation

Hello all python developers,
I was playing with python lists and Pandas library and am having a trouble in a list manipulation tasks. I want to merge all test_list[i][0] dictionary items into one nested list index, according to same state name at index 0 of each nested list.

Sample Input:

```
test_list= [['Alabama', {'Baldwin County': 182265}],
 ['Alabama', {'Barbour County': 27457}],
 ['Arkansas', {'Newton County': 8330}],
 ['Arkansas', {'Perry County': 10445}],
 ['Arkansas', {'Phillips County': 21757}],
 ['California', {'Madera County': 150865}],
 ['California', {'Marin County': 252409}],
 ['Colorado', {'Adams County': 441603}],
 ['Colorado', {'Alamosa County': 15445}],
 ['Colorado', {'Arapahoe County': 572003}]
]
```

Sample Output:

```
test_list1= [['Alabama', {'Baldwin County': 182265, 'Barbour County': 27457}],
 ['Arkansas', {'Newton County': 8330, 'Perry County': 10445, 'Phillips County': 21757}],
 ['California', {'Madera County': 150865, 'Marin County': 252409}],
 ['Colorado', {'Adams County': 441603, 'Alamosa County': 15445, 'Arapahoe County': 572003}]
]
```

I have tried many approaches to solve this but no success so far.I am a beginner python developer.
Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: second sample input you mean expected output? that you want to make your list looke like?

Comment: Yes!! Sample output (edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Approach

- Use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as a way to group data by a common field (in this case, by state).
- For each state, the defaultdict creates a new *dict* which is updated with the *dict.update()* method.
- Turn the result back into a list with `list` applied to the dictionary's items (key/value pairs).

### Working code

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for state, info in test_list:
        d[state].update(info)

>>> result = list(d.items())
>>> pprint(result)
[('Alabama', {'Baldwin County': 182265, 'Barbour County': 27457}),
 ('Arkansas',
  {'Newton County': 8330, 'Perry County': 10445, 'Phillips County': 21757}),
 ('California', {'Madera County': 150865, 'Marin County': 252409}),
 ('Colorado',
  {'Adams County': 441603, 'Alamosa County': 15445, 'Arapahoe County': 572003})]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick respond @raymond-hettinger. Your solution worked efficiently . :)

Comment: If list of lists needed (instead of list of tuples) then result could be written as [[*pair] for pair in d.items()]

Answer (score 2):

#### Python3.5 or later

```
tmp_dict = {}
for lst in test_list:
city = lst[0]
country = lst[1]
if city in tmp_dict:
    tmp_dict[city] = {**tmp_dict[city], **country}
else:
    tmp_dict[city] = country
print(tmp_dict) #you will get dict result
#If you want to get list only
output_result = []
for k in tmp_dict:
    tmp_list.append([k,tmp_dict[k]])
print(output_result) #you will get list result
```